# Installing Xamarin Studio 6.1.2.44, MSBuild Tools 2015 download removed

Tags: xamarin, msbuild

I'm trying to install Xamarin Studios(MonoDevelop) for windows, however Microsoft Build tools 2015 download was been removed which is needed by the installer.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=48159

How can I get the MS Build tools 2015? Is there another way to get it?

Comment: Xamarin Studio is obsolete. On Windows you can only use Visual Studio, and on Mac you should use Visual Studio for Mac. Don't waste your time on obsolete products.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get MSBuild tools and visual c++ build tools 2015 and 2017 from the below link:

[Visual C++ Build Tools](http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools)

Comment: Only need (visual c++ build tools 2015)  -  MSBuild tools 2015 is included in it here http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools

Comment: Yes, he can find that in the submitted link. both links target to same place.

Answer (score 0):

I found this thread cause I also had the same problem and I finally fixed it.

Apparently, MSDN accounts have a ["previously downloaded" section](https://my.visualstudio.com/downloads) where you can find older version of, for example, Microsoft Build Tools. I don't remember downloading it before, but it was there regardless, so give it a shot.

If you don't find it, let me know and I can add a download link to the copy I got.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever may be your purpose, please download from here:

24 MB is the size. Also there are two updates available.

https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=Microsoft%20Build%20Tools%202015